# Use entity framework models across layers?

Tags: entity-framework

I am writing a small MVC application to handle timesheet information for projects I run. It will be hosted, and I am designing it with UI/Service/Data layers. One thing I am torn on, is, can I use the Entity Framework models across all layers? Well, I guess I can, but should I?

All layers will be hosted on the same machine (Except maybe the actual DB..). But accessing the EF models across all layers means all layers, including the UI, needs a reference to the DB layer - bypassing the service.

Is this a safe move?

Maybe I can extract just the models from the EF, and share JUST those across the layers in a form of shared library?

Or should I bite the bullet, and implement DTOs, and translators? So:

DATABASE->EF->TranslaterToDTO->BusinessLogic->ServiceLayer->UI(TranslaterTOViewModel)->View

Answer (score 0):

Actually the EF model **is** your Business Model.

EF is already handling the mapping between your DB model and your Business model (the `MSL` part of the EDMX or your `EntityMapping` classes if your into CodeFirst).

As soon as you're building an MVC application, you should have a View Model. When a request hits a Contoller method, the Model returned to the View should be built by a ModelBuilder. This is up to the ModelBuilder to call your Business Service. That Service returns Business Model that the ModelBuilder will map to the right ViewModel.
Have a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17030058/passing-result-of-procedure-from-entity-framework-to-view/17062314#17062314) where I explain how to work with ModelBuilder.